# .empty() removing jQuery Mobile Native Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a method that populates a dropdown list (I did not write it):

```
    function populateDDListItems(ddlObj, dataToPopulate, showSelectOption) {
        $(ddlObj).empty();
        if (dataToPopulate.length > 1) {
            $(ddlObj).append('<option value="Select" data-theme="a" selected>Select</option>');
        }
        if (dataToPopulate.length > 0) {
            $.each(dataToPopulate, function (idx, val) {
                $(ddlObj).append('<option value="' + val.value + '" data-theme="a">' + val.text + '</option>');
            });
            if (dataToPopulate.length == 1) {
                $(ddlObj).val(dataToPopulate[0].value).attr("selected", "selected");
                $(ddlObj).attr("readonly", "readonly");
            }
        }
    }
```

All of my drop down / select HTML objects have jQuery mobile dropdown applied to them:

[image]

Except one that are generated from this method. I have found that the following line is the culprit:

```
$(ddlObj).empty();
```

If I remove this line the jQuery mobile native menu applies to things coming out of it. However, removing this function also breaks functionality because multiple versions of the list population exist.

Why does this method remove the jQuery mobile native menu and what alternative options do I have to it?

Comment: You should use `$("ddlobj").selectmenu("refresh");` after populating new elements dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You can .hide() it, you can have a hidden element you could clone to the one your using, then that clone could be removed.

In this way, I use a standard Div set for formatting and the clone inherits the properties css etc. The clone then can be changed including .show() and then after it is used up .empty() / .remove () etc.

Comment: Could you please elaborate with an example?

Comment: I use cloning https://github.com/alexmac131/mediaData it is still being written but what I do is have a media result that have to update in a search. The cloning saves having code where I build html css in the javascript.  Cloning is somewhat complex but works well.

Comment: Another less complex example http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_clone